# Is it is required to be data in hive matastore to be used in sql-context from spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Is it is required to be data in hive matastore to be used in sql-context from spark ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Hive metastore is used only with `HiveContext` and is not required if you use standard `SQLContext`.